# Difference between "at" and "in"

Tags: prepositions, at-in

In some time related sentences I saw expressions like *in the morning* and *at night*. For example

> I work **in** the morning

and

> I work **at** night

What is the difference here? Why does the writer use *at* with *night* and *in* with *morning*?
I also know that:

> **at**: In or near the area occupied by; in or near the location of
>
> **in**: Within the limits, bounds, or area of

Comment: You may find http://ell.stackexchange.com better suited for such questions

Comment: Here is a reference: http://www.talkenglish.com/Grammar/prepositions-on-at-in.aspx

Comment: Don't be fooled into thinking these two- and three-letter prepositions have just one or two meanings. The meanings you have provided here only scratch the surface. Think: _at four o'clock, at once, at ease, at odds with,_ [etc.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/at), [etc.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in) (Much of it is idiomatic, too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of prepositions in these time references is idiomatic. And even idiomatic uses are not necessarily exclusive. In US usage, you can say both

> *I work at night*
>
> and
>
> *I work in the night*

The former is the conventional, neutral expression.  The later has a slightly more dramatic tone and may suggest that the work is a bit dangerous, dishonest or spooky.

The opposite is not true. One would not say *I work at morning*. However you could say *I start work at dawn*.

Which preposition goes with which time term simply has to be learned.

Comment: True. But it may be worth noting there are more than twice as many instances of ["when I worked **nights**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22when+I+worked+nights%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books as there are of ["when I worked **at** night"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22when+I+worked+at+night%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). So in some contexts, at least, *no* preposition is the preferred format.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Excellent point. There are numerous examples of alternative expressions where the verb can take a direct object or just be modified by an adverbial phrase, such as  *I worked a farm* and *I worked on a farm*.

Comment: Arguably, _nights_ in 'I work nights' is an adverbial objective rather than a direct object. I'd say that _school_ in 'He taught school' likewise fulfils an adverbial role.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Better explanation.